# Is there a way to use contextual binding in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example in laravel you can specify the class you want to be imported if a certain class was accessed. eg. If I tried to use Filesystem contract, then it would return Storage Facade ([Laravel Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#contextual-binding)). So if some one tried to import axios, it would return a modified version. eg.

```
import axios from 'axios'; // but use window.axios instead
```

Comment: You probably want to look into using some kind of dependency injection library like [Inversify](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things in here, if your library is something that exists on the window space, which means it's provided externally you can just declare it inside your types. The problem with this is that you will need to create the typings manually. More [info here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)

The other option is if you actually want to use some npm package, but resolve the path to something different. This is called path mapping in the typescript land where when you do:

```
import 'jquery'
```

But typescript will actually resolve it to:

```
import 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js'
```

You can read more about path mapping in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)